# How to split multidocument PDF based on bookmark using PDF::API2

Tags: perl, pdf

Is it possible to use PDF::API2 to split a multidocument PDF based on bookmark? For example if *myfile.pdf* contains the following bookmarks:

- bookmark1
- bookmark2
- bookmark3

Then it needs to be splitted to the following individual PDF files:

- bookmark1.pdf
- bookmark2.pdf
- bookmark3.pdf

I can't find any *bookmark* term in the documentation of PDF::API2. Is it what it refers to *outline* ?

Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, Adobe refers to bookmarks as "outlines" in the PDF specification

Answer (score 3):

I tried this for a bit in Perl, then gave up and punted the hard work to [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). I still control it from Perl though. Here's an example script where my bookmarks had titles like "Chapter 1" and "Appendix 1". You can probably adapt this script, but realize some of the stuff is particular to my use. I also am using some new features, but if you don't want to use Perl 5.13, you can easily switch out those parts:

```
use 5.013;

use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec::Functions;
use File::Path qw(make_path);

my $pdftk = 'pdftk';


    my $file = $ARGV[0];
    say ("\n$0 <FILENAME>") && exit 1 unless $file;

my $dir  = dirname( $file ) || '.';
my $output_dir = $ARGV[1] || $dir;

unless( -e $output_dir ) {
    make_path $output_dir, { mode => 0755 } unless -e $output_dir;
    die "mkdir failed: $!" unless -e $output_dir;
    }


my $string = `$pdftk @{[quotemeta($file)]} dump_data output -`;

my( $last_page ) = $string =~ m/NumberOfPages: (\d+)/;
say "last page is $last_page";

my $regex = qr/
    BookmarkTitle:      \s+ (?<title>.*?) \s+
    BookmarkLevel:      \s+ (?<level>\d+) \s+
    BookmarkPageNumber: \s+ (?<page>\d+)
    /x;

my @page_numbers;
while( $string =~ /$regex/g ) {
    next unless $+{level} == 1;
    push @page_numbers, [ @+{ qw(title page) } ];
    }

say "Last index is $#page_numbers";

# Chapter&#160;1.&#160;Introduction
while( my( $index, $elem ) = each @page_numbers ) {
    last if $index == $#page_numbers;
    $page_numbers[$index]->[0] =~ s/&#160;/ /g;
    unshift @$elem,
                    $page_numbers[$index]->[0] =~ s/(?:Chapter|Appendix)\s+(\d+|[ABC]|).?\s+//g

            ?
        $1
            :
        'XX';
    last if $index == $#page_numbers;

    push @$elem, $page_numbers[$index+1]->[-1] - 1;     
    }
unshift @{ $page_numbers[-1] }, 'XX';
push @{ $page_numbers[-1] }, $last_page;

print Dumper( \@page_numbers );

# pdftk A=one.pdf B=two.pdf cat A1-7 B1-5 A8 output combined.pdf
foreach my $elem ( @page_numbers ) {
    my $chapter = $elem->[1] =~ s/\s+/_/rg;
    my $filename = catfile( $output_dir, "$elem->[0].$chapter.pdf" );
    say "Splitting Chapter $elem->[0] $elem->[1]";
    print "Running ", join ' ', $pdftk, $file, 'cat', "$elem->[2]-$elem->[3]", 'output', $filename, "\n";
    system $pdftk, $file, 'cat', "$elem->[2]-$elem->[3]", 'output', $filename;
    }
```